# Update Shopping Cart button in checkout/cart does not update the quantity when clicked

Tags: checkout, cart, shopping-cart, ce-1.9.2.0

Using Magento 1.9.2 - Update Shopping Cart button on checkout/cart page will not update the quantity when clicked.

Numerous posts regarding this issue suggest adding the following code

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml(‘formkey’); ?>
```

after

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">
```

in the cart.phtml file.

I did this however it did not fix the issue.

Here is the code for the button:

```
<button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Cart') ?>" class="button btn-update"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

Comment: Did you gave description for the each product in wish list?

Answer (score 7):

Found the solution.

I replaced

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml(‘formkey’); ?>
```

with

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>"/>
```

inside the fieldset of the form.

Got info from this article http://www.bricksandmortarweb.com/blog/update-cart-working-magento-1-9/

Comment: Mark your self answered answer as the accepted answer please \o/

Comment: Weird that you don't have formkey on `getBlockHtml()`, because is the same that de code with you replaced it.

Comment: However my upvote :)